# Drupal post to facebook

Tags: 7, social-network

Is there a way to make Drupal post to facebook?

I want the user to be able to create an article, and when user does that, it automatically posts information of the new article to a Facebook account. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked into any APIs on the facebook side of things? I seem to recall reading recently that facebook started blocking external posting like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a look at [Drupal For Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb), although there's only a dev version for `D7`

Comment: here's a demo site for the same http://www.drupalforfacebook.org/

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [Facebook Autopost](http://drupal.org/project/fb_autopost). There is a video tutorial on how to set up everything to do it easily.

With this module you will be able to post Links, Posts, Events, Questions, … linked to Drupal events.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Autopost social](https://www.drupal.org/project/autopost_social) module is still in dev version, but it work for facebook, twitter.

> Autopost social is a module to publish posts to multi Social network
>   (Facebook, Twitter) when you add/edit a new content.

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 8 the [social api](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_api) was introduced. Acutally the rewritten and harmonised successor of Drupal for facebook.