# Autopost using checkbox

Tags: nodes, social-network

I have used facebook autopost module using rules but  what I would like is a little checkbox saying: publish to facebook on the node edit page. Does anyone know a module that could help me achieve this? Thanks !

Comment: I'm sure you found quite a lot of modules when you used one of Internet search engines to search for "drupal facebook", so could you please tell us what have you found and why they don't satisfy you?

Comment: I havn't found any such option yet can you please help me in this

Comment: Oh come on, haven't you found [Facebook Post](https://drupal.org/project/fb_post), [Facebook Autopost](https://drupal.org/project/fb_autopost), [Post to Facebook](https://drupal.org/project/fridge)...? None of them? I know Google now personalizes results and you can train it to show you wrong ones, but your case looks to be on the extreme side if you have missed all 3.

Comment: Related: [Drupal post to facebook](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/17019/16495)

Comment: I have used facebook autopost module and used rules for this i need a checkbox in edit content so that only on checking that it post my link to faceboook

Comment: can any one help me in this

Comment: Relax, some questions are answered days or weeks after they are asked. Comments are only to ask for clarifications and similar purposes, not to "bump" your question. For question bumping you need to either edit it to make it better, or earn [enough reputation to start a bounty](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I made this work.

Added a simple Boolean to the node type called field_post_to_facebook. 
In the rule, added a condition of Data Value is Empty.
The Data Selector will be node:field-post-to-facebook.
Choose negate to make sure that it reacts when the checkbox is selected.

I hope this helps.